# Can someone explain to me in what language this API code is written in?

Tags: api

I am supposed to create an API using this code. However I am not sure what language this is written in.

Comment: looks like javascript object notation (json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently doing a curl using a shell:

See what is a shell(bash for example):

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne-Again_shell

You are sending data using POST request, and for sending this data you are using a JSON format file.

I think you will have to create a webservice that accept JSON input

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_Object_Notation

Please be more specific in your question, if it is not what you want.